Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context IN MINIKUBE
When I run
minikube version it shows an error with the minikube version number:
W0609 18:07:59.775242    2068 main.go:291] Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open C:\Users\user\.docker\contexts\meta\37a8eec1ce19687d132fe29051dca629d164e2c4958ba141d5f4133a33f0688f\meta.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
minikube version: v1.33.1
commit: 5883c09216182566a63dff4c326a6fc9ed2982ff

How do I fix this?
Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open C:


Does this answer your question? Unable to access Minikube! message starting miniKube worries me: "Unable to resolve the Docker CLI context" "The system cannot find the path"

I had the same issue. Try resetting Docker and updating it. I'm not sure if it will work for you, though.
